# What made Loki think he is the rightful heir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world

Here's one of the first dialogues between Odin and Loki in *Thor: The Dark World*:

> Odin: All this because Loki desires a throne.
>
> Loki: It is my birthright.

Loki's mention of **birthright** made no sense; because he knew he is an adopted child.

Also, if it was to birthright, Thor was elder.

So what made Loki think he should've been the future king?

Comment: *"Only one of you can ascend to the throne, but both of you were born to be kings"*

Comment: A non-eldest child can inherit a throne if the eldest is, in some way, unworthy of it.  Clearly Loki does not think Thor is worthy of anything.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"A" throne (if not Asgard's) is Loki's birthright because he is [the son of Laufey, the king of the Ice Giants](https://youtu.be/kNDEEYPx54c?t=80). He might very well feel that Odin owes him a throne (since as an adopted Asgardian he can no longer claim the throne of the Ice Giants).

Answer (score 17):

Odin raised both Thor and Loki as princes of Asgard ready for the throne but knew only one of them would get that chance, it happened to be Thor.

> **Odin:** Only one of you can ascend to the throne. But both of you, were born to be kings.
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

In Loki’s eyes Thor probably lost the right to the throne forever after Odin cast him out in *Thor*. In that case the right to the throne would have passed to him and hence why it was not his birthright: with Thor having lost that right.

Of course he also still feels like as the son of Laufey he is owed a throne as we see come out later in life when talking to Thanos.

> **Loki:** I, Loki, Prince of Asgard, Odinson, the rightful King of Jotunheim, God of Mischief, do hereby pledge to you, my undying fidelity

Comment: Indeed. If not the throne of Asgard, then of one of its vassal realms.

Comment: This impression was probably reinforced by being made essentially regent while Odin took a nap in Thor